# How to invoke method on double click in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of files populated in modal window when user click on file i have invoked `downloadServerFile` method that is happening on single click , How can i invoke this method on double click using AngularJs ?

main.html

```
<td ng-click="downloadServerFile(file.filename)" class="noBorder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>{{file.filename}}
                    <span class="pull-right text-danger" style="padding-left: 25px" ng-if="file.mostRecent">*</span></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`ngDblclick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick) instead of ng-click which will allows you to specify custom behavior on a dblclick event.

```
 <td ng-dblclick="downloadServerFile(file.filename)" class="noBorder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>{{file.filename}}                       <span class="pull-right text-danger" style="padding-left: 25px" ng-if="file.mostRecent">*</span></td>
```

[**DEMO APP**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/xsqsprzg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-dblclick` angular directive instead of ng-click. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick)

```
<td ng-dblclick="downloadServerFile(file.filename)" class="noBorder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>{{file.filename}}<span class="pull-right text-danger" style="padding-left: 25px" ng-if="file.mostRecent">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-dblclick

```
<element ng-dblclick="expression"></element>

<div ng-controller="SampleController">
    <a ng-dblclick="showAlert()">Double Click Here </a>
</div>

app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showAlert = function () {
        alert("This is an example of ng-dblclick");
    }
}]);
```